# PHP - mysql merged tables showing in one row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the problem that I have connected two tables (members and invoices). But now I want to show in one table per row one person in which months the invoice was paid (status: 1) and in which months not (status: 0).

My SQL-query: `SELECT inv.month, inv.year from members_velbert mv INNER JOIN invoices inv ON mv.id=inv.user_id`

Result in SQL: [image: result sql]

How it should look like:
[image]

It don't need full implementation. I need only the idea how i could display it using PHP and HTML.

Structure table 1 (members):

```
|ID | surname |  lastname      |    
|---| --------|----------------|
| 1 | Joe     |  Doe           |    
| 2 | Djego   |  Manic         |
| 3 | Max     |  Muster        |
```

Structure table 2 (invoices):

```
|ID  | user_id   |  month   | year | status | amount |
|--- | -------   |  -----   | ---- | ------ | ------ |
| 1  | 1         |  01      | 2021 | 1      | 10.00  |
| 2  | 3         |  01      | 2021 | 1      | 10.00  |
| 3  | 3         |  02      | 2021 | 0      | 10.00  | 
| 4  | 3         |  03      | 2021 | 1      | 10.00  |
| .. | 3         |  ..      | 2021 | 1      | 10.00  |
```

Comment: you have to show the structure of the 2 tables

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I edited it

Comment: Im assuming the query is getting all the data you need, and now you want to print it out with php, is that right? If that is the case can I see the structure of the returned array?

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: MySQL SELECT Statement

```
SELECT 
    mv.firstname,
    mv.surname,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS JANUARY,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FEBRUARY,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MARCH,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS APRIL,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MAY,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS JUNE,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS JULY,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AUGUST,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SEPTEMBER,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OCTOBER,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NOVEMBER,
    CASE WHEN inv.month = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DECEMBER
FROM members_velbert mv 
INNER JOIN invoices inv 
ON mv.id=inv.user_id
WHERE inv.status = 1
GROUP BY user_id;
```

PHP document. You'll need to fetch the query rows as `$rows` before this.

```
<?php

$html = "<table>";
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $html .= "<tr>
                  <td>{$row['firstname']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['lastname']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['JANUARY']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['FEBRUARY']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['MARCH']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['APRIL']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['MAY']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['JUNE']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['JULY']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['AUGUST']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['SEPTEMBER']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['OCTOBER']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['NOVEMBER']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['DECEMBER']}</td>
              <tr>";
}
$html .= "</table>";

echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question, "I need only the idea how i could display it using PHP and HTML"?

Comment: I get now a good SQL table. How i could show it in my table... I have a normal HTML table with <th> and <td>.

Comment: I edited my answer, I now see that you were asking how to display the HTML. If you don't want to write it all in PHP and then echo, you can put PHP tags around each piece of data, but inside `td` tags.

Comment: @solidforge that looks good but status is missing in query...

Comment: @solidforge if i execute the sql query than i can see djego in 3 rows...

Comment: I added status in the WHERE clause and added GROUP BY. It's hard to test since I don't have the database to work with.

Comment: Go ahead and upload a table (with fake data if you want) to data.world and I can see what I can do